# Stumped on series question

Tags: sequences-and-series

This seems to be the hardest series question I've encountered. I am puzzled as to what test needs to be performed. I don't see any insignificant terms to drop for a comparison test, the ratio test yields an ugly and (to me) incomprehensible result, the root test does the same, and I attempted the alternating series test but was marked incorrect. Any thoughts? [image]

Comment: First thing you should always check when doing series is the Divergence Test....

Comment: Try limit of the terms. What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-3)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{2n+3}}$?

Comment: The result from the ratio test should not be incomprehensible to you.  What do you get?

Comment: I completely agree with @saulspatz -- the results of the Ratio Test are not incomprehensible. And the output of the Root Test is just as comprehensible too. Hint: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\text{polynomial in }n}=1$.